# how to retrieve element from soap object

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap2

I am trying to create a  Android app to get data from Web Services server. Here is my code:

```
SoapObject results = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
```

The below string is my result. How can I get userid, usersname,accountname,accountid and accounttype from the soap object?

```
LogInResponse{LogInResult=anyType{schema=anyType{element=anyType{complexType=anyType{choice=anyType{element=anyType{complexType=anyType{sequence=anyType{element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; }; }; }; }; }; }; }; diffgram=anyType{DocumentElement=anyType{user=anyType{userid=""; accountid=; accountname=; usersname=; accounttype=; }; }; }; }; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to say getProperty(propertyname)
Details:
http://kobjects.org/ksoap2/doc/api/org/ksoap2/serialization/SoapObject.html